# Electron Linux Video Hardware Acceleration

Tags: electron, hardware-acceleration

Im having a hard time getting hardware acceleration for videos working in electron running on Linux (ARM64) and Linux (Intel64). Im not sure if this is an issue with the flags electron is using for chromium or if its more an issue at drive level on the host machines. Or maybe it's just not possible. Both machines are running Chromium 95 snap 64 bit.

When running chromium (ARM64) without any flags and running chrome://gpu i get the following:

[image: chrome://gpu]

When running chromium (ARM64) with --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder i get the following:
[image: chrome://gpu]

This leads me to believe that when calling chrome with the flag hardware acceleration should be working. Just to add to the complexity of this if i go to youtube and check media it looks like it may still be disabled (even with the flags):

[image]

I have read through a number of articles titled 'how to enable hardware acceleration in electron'. Most of which list the following flags to provide:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-gpu-blacklist')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-gpu-rasterization')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-accelerated-video')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-accelerated-video-decode')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('use-gl', 'desktop')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'VaapiVideoDecoder')
```

I have tried all of these but nothing seems to make any difference. When running a video in electron it has the following properties:

[image]

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction with this? Thank you.

Comment: It may very well be that the video hardware or its driver does not natively support the codecs you are trying to decode. You've said that you were testing on ARM64. What make is that machine, does it have dedicated video hardware? Also, Chromium does not support hardware-decoding on Linux by default, not even when you tell it to. On NVIDIA hardware (and for most codecs also on AMD and Intel cards), you'll have to install the proprietary driver, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. They are running in a VM on a M1 Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been solved. The main issue was the VaAPI driver needing to be installed on the hardware running the application. Secondly the only flags needed was the following:

```js
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'VaapiVideoDecoder')
```